# How to get value from a resolved JavaScript promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Let's say I have a promise `p`. I have the following code:

```
var entries = getEntries();

var getEntries = function() {
    ...SOME_CODE...
    return p.then(function(result) {
        return result;
    });
}
```

Using the debugger, I can see that `result` has the data that I want. How can I save it to the global variable `entries` (`getEntries()` currently returns an undefined value)?

Comment: You don't. You couldn't use the global variable anyway without having waited for the promise. So just return a promise from `getEntries` and store that.

Comment: If you still want to do it: `var entries; getEntries().then(result => { entries = result; }, console.error);`

Comment: `getEntries() currently returns an undefined value` - no, it returns a `Promise` that will resolve to `result`